# How to fix Invalid index to scalar variable?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, jupyter-notebook, k-means

I tried to write K-means algorithm and got this error in line: `points = np.array ([x[j] for j in range (len (x)) if cluster [j] == i])`
anyone can help?

```
from copy import deepcopy

def euclidean_distance (a, b, ax = 1):
    return np.linalg.norm (a - b , axis = ax)

c_prev = np.zeros (c.shape)
clusters = np.zeros (len(x))

distance_differences = euclidean_distance (c, c_prev)

while distance_differences.any () != 0:
    for i in range (len(x)):
        distances = euclidean_distance (x[i], c)
        cluster = np.argmin (distances)
        clusters [i] = cluster
    c_prev = deepcopy (c)
    for i in range (k):
        points = [x[j] for j in range (len(x)) if clusters [j] == i]
        if len(points) != 0:
            c[i] = np.mean (points, axis = 0)

    distance_differences = euclidean_distance (c, c_prev)

colors = ['b', 'r', 'y', 'g', 'c', 'm']
for i in range (k):
    points = np.array ([x[j] for j in range (len (x)) if cluster [j] == i])
    if len(points) > 0:
        plt.scatter (points [:, 0], points [:, 1], s= 10, c = colors [i])
    else:
        print ('Please regenerate your centeroids again')

plt.scatter (points [:, 0], points [:, 1], s= 10, c = colors [i])
plt.scatter(c[:, 0], c[:, 1], marker = '*', s =100, c ='k')
plt.show();
```

Comment: Please elaborate on the error and possibly explain what you're trying to achieve, rather than expecting the reader to know what you mean beforehand!

Comment: also what are `c`, `x` & `k`?

Comment: sorry for short explanation. i wanted to write k-means clustering algorithm and test it. `c` is the random centroids, `x` is a matrix containing all example points and `k` is clusters' number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you have a typo in the line,

```
points = np.array ([x[j] for j in range (len (x)) if cluster [j] == i])
```

It should read,

```
points = np.array ([x[j] for j in range (len (x)) if clusters[j] == i])
```

As `cluster` is just a scalar (ie only has a single value) & `clusters` is the array

Comment: yes that was my mistake and it works now! thank you!